# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 _cJSON trying to compile test app

Tags: macos, cc

I'm trying to compile using:

```
cc -I ./curl-7.58.0/include/curl -I ./cJSON-master alexa_request_simple_demo.c
```

and I'm getting the error stated in the title. Curl and cJSON both compile fine on my MBP. I've tried including

```
-L ./cJSON-master/build
```

but I get the same error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cJSON_AddFalseToObject", referenced from:
      _curl_sync_state in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
      _curl_send_audio_content in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_cJSON_AddItemToArray", referenced from:
      _curl_sync_state in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
      _curl_send_audio_content in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_cJSON_AddItemToObject", referenced from:
      _curl_sync_state in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
      _curl_send_audio_content in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_cJSON_AddNumberToObject", referenced from:
      _curl_sync_state in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
      _curl_send_audio_content in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_cJSON_AddStringToObject", referenced from:
      _curl_sync_state in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
      _curl_send_audio_content in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_cJSON_CreateArray", referenced from:
      _curl_sync_state in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
      _curl_send_audio_content in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_cJSON_CreateObject", referenced from:
      _curl_sync_state in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
      _curl_send_audio_content in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_cJSON_Delete", referenced from:
      _curl_sync_state in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
      _curl_send_audio_content in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_cJSON_Print", referenced from:
      _curl_sync_state in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
      _curl_send_audio_content in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_easy_cleanup", referenced from:
      _main in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_easy_init", referenced from:
      _main in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_easy_setopt", referenced from:
      _curl_send_audio_cfg in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
      _curl_downchannel_cfg in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
      _curl_ping_cfg in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
      _curl_sync_state in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
      _curl_send_audio_content in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_easy_strerror", referenced from:
      _curl_downchannel_cfg in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
      _curl_ping_cfg in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_formadd", referenced from:
      _curl_sync_state in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
      _curl_send_audio_content in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_formfree", referenced from:
      _main in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_multi_add_handle", referenced from:
      _main in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_multi_cleanup", referenced from:
      _main in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_multi_fdset", referenced from:
      _main in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_multi_info_read", referenced from:
      _main in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_multi_init", referenced from:
      _main in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_multi_perform", referenced from:
      _main in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_multi_remove_handle", referenced from:
      _main in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_multi_setopt", referenced from:
      _main in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_multi_timeout", referenced from:
      _main in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_slist_append", referenced from:
      _curl_send_audio_cfg in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
      _curl_downchannel_cfg in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
      _curl_ping_cfg in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_slist_free_all", referenced from:
      _main in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
  "_curl_version", referenced from:
      _main in alexa_request_simple_demo-48b802.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I needed to -l the dynlib files for both libraries (noobie mistake)

```
gcc -I ./curl-7.58.0/include/curl alexa_request_simple_demo.c -I ./cJSON-master -L ./cJSON-master/build ./libcjson.1.7.1.dylib ./libcurl.4.dylib
```